# regex java , limit of numbers ,unlimited whitespace and only one char

Tags: java, regex

I try to write regex in Java. I want to create phone number regex limited to {9,12} numbers. Between numbers it's possible to use whitespace and only one char slash , but whitespace and slash does not count into limit

For example:

1. 12345678 - False ( only 8 digits)
2. 123456789 - True ( 9 digits)
3. 123456789012 - True ( 12 digits)
4. 1234 567 89 012 - True ( 12 digits and white space)|
5. 12345678901234 - False ( 13 digits beyond the limit)
6. 123/456 782 321 - True ( 12 digits , one char slash, and whitespace)
7. 123456//787 78 - False ( 11 digits because double char slash)

I want whitespaces and slash character to be independent of a limit.

Thank you!

Comment: Simplest one would be `[0-9]{9,12}`. But then it won't be enough for validation, as there might be restriction on first few digits according to country code and ofcourse `000000000` such numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Between numbers it's possible to use whitespace and only one char slash , but whitespace and slash does not count into limit

Considering this specification following regex matches without taking into account `whitespaces` and `slash`.

**Regex:** `^(?:[\/\s]?[0-9]){9,12}$`

[image: Regex Demo]

Comment: Thank you! i have one more question: is it possible to put a only one slash  at the begining and the end? For example : 
/123456789123 or 123456789123/ , more slashes return false For example: //123456789012 or 123456789012//

Comment: That one slash should be counted  ?

Comment: @firstontheworld: `^\/?(?:[\/\s]?[0-9]){9,12}\/?$` will do.

Comment: You are amazing !! Thank you very much!!

Comment: it is possible to put only one slash within string?
For example :  12345/65765 - TRUE   ,  1234/5436/767 - false because two slash with in expression

Comment: @firstontheworld: You really need to put all specification at once in your post. Modifying specification after an answer has been accepted is not encouraged.